# What is the compat method to use finishAffinity() for API 14?

Tags: android

Since finishAffinity() was only introduced in API 16, but my app targets 14+. How do I get this to work for 14+?

Thank you!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Got it.

Use ActivityCompat.finishAffinity(this); (with v4 support library)

Comment: and now see ActivityCompat.java source and see how it is done, ypu will be surprised

Comment: So basically the problem still persists below API 15.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue with API 15.